# Dynamically loading react pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am very new to react world. I was gone through many examples of react, flux, webpack etc. I found that when I create a page as a react component it is bundled by webpack and loaded in the page.

How to load react components dynamically when I click each tab.
I have done this using reat-router, but the problem is in the index.js I have to include all the tab components.

```
var Tab1 = require('./components/Tab1');
var Tab2 = require('./components/Tab2');
var Tab3 = require('./components/Tab3');

render((
  <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Tab1}>
      <Route path="about" component={Tab2} />
      <Route path="users" component={Tab3} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

is there any way to load these components dynamically without including the components early in the page?
or webpack will handle this?
When i search the bundle.js I found all the components there. In my case each components will be a heavy scripts, so it is not good to load all the components in the first loading itself.

Comment: Its a nice feature to have the different components lazy load. But I would strongly recommend against it. When we load an app on the user end, I always prefer that the user has all the essential parts of my code. Only the data to be passed into those components should be delegated. Also with multiple parts of your code loading dynamically, you will have hard time doing cache invalidation on production environment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but is that a good idea to load all the components at the first load itself? because I have tons of codes in each component store for parsing the complex data. When i load component I have to load these stores. how to handle this situation? in the question I have just added a sample example but in real life I have tons of code per component store.

Comment: Yeah you can go ahead and concat, transform & uglify all you code and just use that one js file to be loaded on the users browser. In my current AngularJS project we have ~100 different components (with multiple parts in each) and couple of 3rd party libs, all compressed and uglified into one js. Version-ed with each release to invalidate cache. There is one difference though. We convert all html templates to one huge template cache js and load that additionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution from here

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/advanced/DynamicRouting.md

https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

```
require.ensure(["module-a", "module-b"], function(require) {
    var a = require("module-a");
    // ...
});
```